# In LightningOut, firing an event multiple times from the VF page javascript to LightningOut component gives Event error

Tags: lightning-out

I've seen several questions regarding this issue, but none of the answers work in LightningOut. When an event is fired from the VF page's javascript (VF page event to Lightning Component), it gives an error when it is fired more than once (I am sending changed param values): Event.setParams(): cannot modify all params in an event that has already been fired. : false -- also if I removed the setParams, it just says you can't fire it after it's already been fired. This is true for either APPLICATION or COMPONENT events. Any ideas how to get the event to be able to be fired more than once?

Comment: You cannot fire either type of event more than once. You need a new one every time you want to trigger an event.

Comment: The way our app is set up that could be a large (and unknown) number of events. Any tricks or work-arounds?

Comment: You need to call $A.get each time to create a new event.